# How to display payment instructions in magento email

Tags: magento

I'm using `{{var order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getTitle()}}` to show payment method in custom email template because `{{var payment_html}}` got me no results (empty field). How can I add **payment method AND payment instructions** to custom email, so it will show same block as used in /app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to achieve that too.
Have you tried with this?

```
{{var order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getDescription()}}
```